# Trade offs between FetchType.LAZY and FetchType.EAGER?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My current understanding is `FetchType.EAGER` is preferred only if:

1. the fetch strategy for the association is `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` or `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`, so Hibernate will make a batch query when loading the root entity.
2. we want to ensure the root entity and the associated entity are loaded within the same transaction, but this can also be enforce through other mechanisms(e.g. using `@Transactional`).

In other cases, `FetchType.LAZY` always help decrease number of db requests. Is this correct?

Comment: as far as I'm aware, if you would need to make another call to fetch the data then use EAGER. if you dont care about that data... use LAZY.

Comment: When using the 2nd level cache something to consider is that some entities will often be in the cache so you don't need to hit the database, even with a join. For instance if you have ~200 country entities it would make sense to cache them and mark the corresponding associations as lazy.

Answer (score 0):

1. As for the relation between `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` and `FetchType.LAZY`, you can find in the [documentation the following](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-join):

> ... `FetchMode.JOIN` is useful for when entities are fetched directly, via their identifier or natural-id.
>
> Also, *the `FetchMode.JOIN` acts as a `FetchType.EAGER` strategy. Even if we mark the association as `FetchType.LAZY`, the `FetchMode.JOIN` will load the association eagerly.*

2. You can find the following recommendation in [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies) of the documentation:

> *The Hibernate recommendation is to statically mark all associations lazy and to use dynamic fetching strategies for eagerness.*
>
> This is unfortunately at odds with the JPA specification which defines that all one-to-one and many-to-one associations should be eagerly fetched by default.
>
> Hibernate, as a JPA provider, honors that default.